# Android java :Passing with the path between two activity

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm new in android developing and currently develop an CalendarNote app.

1. By pick the date to create a folder and the folder name is the date.
2. After pick the date and successfully created the date folder move to
   text interface.
3. create folder and text interface are two different activity.
4. Now, the problem is I want to save the txt file to  the folder that
   I just created.
5. I try to getText from the date I picked to the text activity, but
   not successful.

I did a lot of research and tried a lot related code, still not success.
Anyone can please help me or give me some guide so that I won't lost . Thanks.

The following bellow is the create folder code:

```
btn_cFolder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {       
  public void onClick(View v) 
            {
             String dateN = edit_date.getText().toString();

             new AlertDialog.Builder(DatePickerActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK)  

                .setTitle("Create Folder")
                .setMessage("Confirm to create " + dateN +" folder ?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                         Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                         String dateN = edit_date.getText().toString();
                         edit_date.setTypeface(edit_date.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/CalendarNote/" + dateN);
                            boolean success = true;
                                if (!folder.exists()) {
                                    success = folder.mkdirs();
                                }
                                if (success) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have successfully created." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                        Intent w = new Intent(DatePickerActivity.this, SelectTypeActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(w);


                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Failed to create." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                }

                    }
                 })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        // do nothing
                    }
                 })
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                 .show();
            }
   });
```

And this is the create txt file code:

```
public void SaveListener() {         
    imb_savefile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imb_savefile);

    imb_savefile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

             edit_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_date);

            String t = edit_title.getText().toString();
             new AlertDialog.Builder(WriteNoteActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK)
            .setTitle("Save Note")
            .setMessage("Confirm to save " + t +"?")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
             String content = edit_content.getText().toString();
             String title = edit_title.getText().toString();
             String dateN = edit_date.getText().toString();
             boolean success = true;
                 try {
                    File sdCardDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
                    File targetFile;
                    targetFile = new File(sdCardDir.getCanonicalPath()  
                            + "/CalendarNote/"+ dateN);
                    File file=new File(targetFile + "/"+title+".txt");

                    if(!targetFile.exists()){
                        success = targetFile.mkdir();  
                    }
                    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");  
                    raf.seek(file.length());  

                    raf.write(content.getBytes());  
                    raf.close();  
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                 if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have successfully created." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Failed to create." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Note have successfully saved." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
             })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Note Cancelled." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
             })
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
             .show();
        }

    });

}
```

The **dateN** is the key to create folder .

**[Updateted 15/3/2014]**
Hi actually after pick the date **(DatePickerActivity) >>** select type of note **(SelectTypeActivity) >>** write the txt file **(WriteNoteActivity)**. This is the process. So far i use @Hamid Shatu suggestion this is really helpful ! But I have to change the intent **SelectTypeActivity.class to WriteNoteActivity.class** like this it will success, how can I no need to skip the **SelectTypeActivity** also able to do that ? =)
Sorry for my broken English.

Comment: Anonymous class are a nice feature of Java, when you go down multiple levels, it makes the code very hard to read and causes crazy indentation. Try breaking this code down into multiple methods.

Comment: Can you add some more information about what is the problem you are experiencing? When you try the code: what does happen? what are you expecting to happen? How are they different? If you are getting an exception, include the exception with the stack trace.

Comment: @unholysampler I want the txt file save to the folder that I create.

Comment: @unholysampler Hi I have solve the problem but new problem came out.
Any suggestion to not skip the SelectTypeActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your folder path to `SelectTypeActivity` through `putExtra()` method of `Intent` as below...

```
String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/CalendarNote/" + dateN;
File folder = new File(folderPath);

boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdirs();
}

if (success) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have successfully created." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    Intent w = new Intent(DatePickerActivity.this, SelectTypeActivity.class);
    w..putExtra("folderpath", folderPath);
    startActivity(w);

} else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Failed to create." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
```

Retrieve that folder path from `Extra` using `getStringExtra()` method in `SelectTypeActivity` class as below...

```
//File sdCardDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
//File targetFile;
//targetFile = new File(sdCardDir.getCanonicalPath()  
                        + "/CalendarNote/"+ dateN);
String folderPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("folderpath");
File file=new File(folderPath + "/"+title+".txt");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your good advice but when i do so 
targetFile.exists and targetFile.mkdir will become red line.

Comment: Hi actually after pick the date (DatePickerActivity) >> select type of note (SelectTypeActivity) >> write the txt file (WriteNoteActivity).
This is the process. So far i use your suggestion this is really helpful ! But I have to change the intent SelectTypeActivity.class to WriteNoteActivity.class like this it will success, how can I no need to skip the SelectTypeActivity also able to do that ? =)